# jQuery UI spinner onchage return old value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spinner, onchange

Considering the following snippet

```
<input type="text" id="age" value="" maxlength="2" style="width: 30px;" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#age").spinner({
        min: 1,
        max: 99,
        spin: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).change();
        }
    }).val(35);
    $("#age").change(function() {
        console.log($("#age").val());
    });
</script>
```

Why when `onchange` event occurs by pressing Up/Down key or clicking the spinner it log the old spinner value?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac7WL/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin takes some time to update the value. 
Try using the build in callback, ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-spin

**as a seperate event.**

```
$("#age").on( "spin", function( event, ui ) { 
    console.log(ui.value)
});
```

**or as a option on init**

```
$("#age").spinner({
    min: 1,
    max: 99,
    spin: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui.value)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the '**stop**' event instead of the '**spin**' event.

For me, this worked, while using the 'spin' event gave me the same problem as the PO.

Quoting from the jQueryUI-API: (emphasis by me)

> stop( event, ui ) Type: spinstop Triggered *after* a spin.

```
$( ".selector" ).spinner({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

> Bind an event listener to the spinstop event:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "spinstop", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Source: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#event-stop

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)